# Returning from java method before all threads are done

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

Is it possible to return from a java method that started threads before all the threads are done?

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ExecutorSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            service.execute(() -> {
                while (true) {
                }
            });
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

This doesn't return for some reason that I don't understand. Why is the main thread's return affected by the worker threads being stuck?

Comment: How do you know the method doesn't return?

Comment: @khelwood I tested and it's stuck on main.

Comment: @ScaryWombat shutdownNow doesn't work either because it is only best attempt and doesn't actually shut down the worker threads

Comment: @Jessica You gotta show us the results of your tests, probably why someone downvoted you. Also, you should show the tests IN your code example.

Comment: Place the code in another method, call it from `main` and after the other method returns print something in `main` to test if other method returns.

Comment: @MichaelButscher that doesn't help

Comment: @ScaryWombat that doesn't do it either

Comment: Are you sure that you are not mixing up the end of `main` with the end of the program? These are different things here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `main` method *is* returning, but the problem is that your JVM isn't exiting. You can test this by renaming your `main` method to something else, like `doMain()`, and then writing `main` as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    doMain();
    System.out.printf("here");
}
```

You'll see that you do get the output, but the program doesn't end.

What's happening is that `Executors.newCachedThreadPool` uses the [default thread factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#defaultThreadFactory--), which creates non-daemon threads. When your `main` method returns, the JVM will wait for all non-daemon threads to finish (that's what differentiates them from daemon threads -- the JVM doesn't wait for those). Since all of your Runnables run forever, the non-daemon threads will never finish, and the JVM will never exit.

What can you do? Some options:

- Use the overload [`newCachedThreadPool(ThreadFactory)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool-java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory-), supplying a ThreadFactory that creates daemon threads
- Use [`shutdownNow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--) on your ExecutorService. That will send an interrupt on each of the running threads. You'll still have to check for that on each thread, either by calling a method that throws `InterruptedException` or by explicitly calling `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`.

For the `shutdownNow` approach, note that interrupting a thread by itself is *not* enough to stop it -- the code running on that thread has to cooperate by checking for its interrupted state (using one of those two approaches) and appropriately exiting. For instance, you could replace `while(true)` with `while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())`.

Comment: @yshavit From your answer, it seems that supplying a thread factory that creates daemon threads is the better way. Is there any downsides to that approach?

Comment: @Jessica: The downside to daemon threads is they go away with no chance for cleanup if the last nondaemon thread exits. Don’t use daemon threads for anything that you care about getting finished in a controlled way.

Comment: @NathanHughes Cool is there a java native way to build this factory? I tried the guava ThreadFactoryBuilder which works but a native java way would be better

Comment: Happy to help, Jessica! I don't know of a better way to create a custom Thread factory than guava's, or to just write your own. Creating Thread isn't hard, and the javadocs are hopefully fairly self-explanatory. (Also, thanks for fixing that typo, @NathanHughes!)